# Set Environment Variable during Setup

Tags: c#

Is there any way to change a value of a setting in the `Settings.settings` file of a C# project during the installation stage. I have 2 projects in 1 solution, 1 is the actual project, and the other is the `Setup and Deployment > Setup Project` project.

Comment: Why do you not just have the values in app.config and then you can change them as much as you want?

Comment: Where's that? and What does it do? and How do I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might already have an App.Config file. If not make sure try clicking the "Show all files" icon in Solution Explorer. Then, if you still do not have one right-click your project and select "Add new Item" there is a item type of config file. For more info see [MSDN's documentation on adding a config file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms184658.asp)

Basically it's an XML file in which you add values you want to use to configure your application by using:

```
    <configuration>
       <appSettings>
          <add key="My Key" value="Some Value"/>
       </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

You access the config file by including System.Configuration in your code and then use the following:

```
string myValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"];
```

This way you can control values through deployments - we have config files for our dev, UAT and live environments with things such as database/web service locations and items specific to the deployment.  It's a much easier way of doing things IMO.